# Password form redirection to belonging post

Tags: php, functions, password

My idea is that the visitor enters the password on a page and than the wordpress post with belonging password load if there is one.

Here is the code:

Form on page:

```
<form method="post" action="">
  <input type="password" name="passwordfield">
  <input type="hidden" name="homepagepassword" value="1">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Function.php:

```
function dopasswordstuff(){
    if(isset($_POST['homepagepassword'])){
    $post_password = $_POST['passwordfield'];
    global $wpdb;
    $post_id = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_password = %s", $post_password) );
    $q = new WP_Query( 'p=$post_id' );
    if($q->have_posts()){
        while($q->have_posts()){
            $q->the_post();
            wp_redirect( get_permalink ());
            die();
        }
    } else {
        // oh dear, there isnt a post with this 'password', put a redirect to a fallback here
        wp_redirect('http://www.google.com');
        die();
    }
    wp_reset_query();
    }
}
add_action('init','dopasswordstuff');
```

No matter what I do, and no matter what password I enter, the function just directs me to the first post on my blog. Can anybody shed some light on this?

Comment: Why don't you use the built-in password protection?

Comment: Built-in password protection is not working the way I would like. I'm trying to direct users to a certain post (via form on a page) based on a password entered in post settings. eg. if someone enters "pass1" he will be directed to a post which has set password "pass".

Comment: You can do that with the built-in password protection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is all you need to make this work, plus your actual form of course:

```
function dopasswordstuff(){
   if(isset($_POST['homepagepassword'])){
    global $wpdb;
    $post_password = trim($_POST['passwordfield']);
    $post_id = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_password = %s", $post_password) );
    if (!empty($post_id)) {
      wp_redirect(get_permalink($post_id));
    }
    exit;
   }
}
add_action('template_redirect','dopasswordstuff');
```

I simplified your function considerably by leveraging the fact that [`get_permalink`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink) will accept a post ID a parameter.

I hooked to `template_redirect` instead of `init` which seemed more appropriate.

Comment: WOW, hell yeah you're awesome!
There is still one issue - it seems this function doesn't register that you already entered password so once you are redirected to post you have to re-enter password.

Comment: I will see what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer with this code which uses cookies (I didn't write it!), however if someone types in the incorrect password I get the white screen of death so if anyone knows how to add the code back in to give a redirect that would be awesome.

```
function dopasswordstuff(){
   if(isset($_POST['homepagepassword'])) {
    global $wpdb;
    $post_password = trim($_POST['passwordfield']);
    $post_id = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_password = %s", $post_password) );
    if (!empty($post_id)) {
      if ( empty( $wp_hasher ) ) {
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/class-phpass.php' );
        // By default, use the portable hash from phpass
        $wp_hasher = new PasswordHash(8, true);
      }
      // 10 days
      setcookie( 'wp-postpass_' . COOKIEHASH, $wp_hasher->HashPassword( stripslashes( $post_password ) ), time() + 864000, COOKIEPATH );
      wp_redirect(get_permalink($post_id));
    }
    exit;
  }
}
add_action('template_redirect','dopasswordstuff');
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly and if you didn't write that code then please properly cite the code's author.